# Is there a closed form for $\sum_{|\gamma|=k} \gamma!$

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider the multi-index $\gamma=(\gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_n)$. Is there a closed form for the sum $\sum_{|\gamma|=k} \gamma!$ in terms of $n$ and $k$? Asymptotics, or good upper bounds are also very helpful.

Here is what I have tried. Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0} i! x^{i+2}$. This generating function satisfies the ODE $x^2f'(x)=f(x)-x$. Then the sum $\sum_{|\gamma|=k} \gamma!$ is the coefficient of $x^{k+2n}$ in $f(x)^n$. However I don't have any means to find this coefficient.

Comment: the generating function of your sum regarded as a sequence in k seems to satisfy the relatively simple nonlinear DE $n x^2 g(x) g''(x) -(n-1)g'(x)^2 + n(3x-1)g'(x)+n^2g(x)^2=0$.  Not sure whether this may be helpful, and I have no time to check right now.  It may well be a triviality, in which case I beg your pardon.

Comment: is there any particular relation of $k$ and $n$ that interests you?

Comment: A closed form is unlikely. For fixed $n$ (or $n$ small compared with $k$) the main contribution will come from the terms where for some $j$, $\gamma_j =k$ and $\gamma_i=0$ for $i\ne j$, so the sum will be asymptotic to $n\cdot k!$. More generally, asymptotic expansion can be obtained in this case  by taking the terms where all but one $\gamma_i$ is a fixed integer. 

Answer (score 3):

Dividing by $(\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_n)!$ you are trying to estimate $$\sum_{\gamma \vdash k}\binom{k}{\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n}^{-1}$$
One way to start would be to write it as an integral over the probability simplex (sum of generalized beta functions) or to try to find some information from the generating function. For $n=2$, for instance the integral representation is $$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}^{-1}=(k+1)\int_{0}^1 \frac{(1-t)^{k+1}-t^{k+1}}{1-2t}dt$$
and the generating function is $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}^{-1}\right)x^k=\frac{2x}{1-x}-\frac{2x}{2-x}-\frac{2x \log(1-x)}{(2-x)^2}$$
from which it is not very hard to see that
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}^{-1} \sim 2+\frac{2}{k-1}$$ so $$\sum_{i=0}^k i!(k-i)!\sim k!\left(2+\frac{2}{k-1}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's try $n=2$.  Maple says:
$$
\sum_{j = 0}^{k} j!(k - j)! = -\Biggl(\mathrm{LerchPhi} (2,1,k) k^{2} + 
\mathrm{LerchPhi} (2,1,k) k + \frac{i \pi k^{2}}{2^{k}} + \frac{i \pi k}{2^{k}} - 3 k - 1\Biggr) \frac{\Gamma (k)}{2}
$$
but doesn't know asymptotics for $\mathrm{LerchPhi}(2,1,k)$.

Comment: This is http://oeis.org/A003149